# Find newline in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013, newline

I have a C++ source file containing many functions.

I want to find the beginning of every function quickly.

How can I form an expression for `)newline{newline`?

The `newline` symbol can be either one of the following:

1. `\n`
2. `\r`
3. `\n\r`
4. `\r\n`

Presumably, the same symbol is used all across the file, so instead of a single expression for all options combined, I need a single expression for each option.

I assume that a regular-expression can be used, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks

Comment: are you asking about the text editor within VS2013?

Comment: @NirMH: Yes, although I assume it would be similar in any other text editor, such as notepad++, etc. Since I'm not 100% sure of that, I had to specify VS2013.

Comment: did you try VSAssist addin for that purpose (similar to C# resharper)

Comment: @NirMH: You mean, for the original purpose of finding the beginning of every function quickly?

Comment: yes/ VSAssist has a feature to go to the beginning of each function. additionaly you can collaspe all function bodys to easily see all functions defined - use CTRL+M+O

Comment: Can't you use the Solution Explorer window?

Comment: @NirMH: Thanks. The ultimate purpose is to place a break-point at the beginning of every function (and it's a very long file). So I figured I would be able to do it quickly with a sequence of F3,F9,F3,F9,... after forming the right expression.

Comment: I would re-phrase your question as you really want to put a breakpoint at ever function first line... people might help you more easily if you'll define the title such as this

Comment: @Mike of SST: Any solution is welcome as far as I'm concerned. My ultimate goal, as mentioned above, is to place a break-point at the beginning of every function. Thanks.

Comment: FYI added the four expressions to my answer, since you said you wanted one each. I had missed that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barak, before we look at individual options, for all options, this will do it:

```
\)[\r\n]+{[\r\n]+
```

The `[\r\n]` is a character class that allows either of `\r` or  `\n`. It is quantified with a `+` which means we are looking for one or more of these characters.

You said you want individual options, so this can be turned to:

1. `\)\r\n{\r\n`
2. `\)\r{\r`
3. `\)\n{\n`
4. `\)\n\r{\n\r` (this sequence of newlines is quite surprising)

[image: VS2013 regex]

Comment: Awesome! The only reason I asked for a single expression for each option, is that I assumed it would be easier to construct such expressions. But the general expression works just fine (and relieves me from the task of finding out which `newline` is in use). Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the *Find* combo-box that I have on VS2013 looks different than the one in your answer (which I believe to be the one in VS2012 downwards).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to use the regex search in VS to find the beginning of each function then this should work for you:

```
\)\r?\n\s*{\r?\n
```

Although that assumes the { is always on the next line with no white space before the line break.

This would be less strict where white space is concerned, but still expect the { to be on the next line and to be followed by a line break:

```
\)\s*\r?\n\s*{\s*\r?\n
```

And this would basically just look for the 2 brackets even if they're on the same line:

```
\)\s*\r?\n?\s*{
```

And if you expect there could be several line breaks between the 2 brackets:

```
\)\s*(\r?\n\s*)*{
```

Last example should find anything that could resemble the beginning of a method. But not sure how strict you want your search to be.